# Google+ shows an internal error occured only when proguarded

Tags: android, google-plus, google-api-java-client

I have followed [this](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/android) document step by step and got my google+ working with my android application.

But after I exported the application to an apk, it always throws an "`internal error occurred`" toast message. I have made sure of correct `SHA1` keys and package names. I have correctly used `proguard`, it does not throw any errors.

Please help me find a way to make my app work after exporting it.

Comment: Check logcat - there is likely a message in there that will add some details. Enable the verbose logging, as described at the bottom of https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started#frequently_asked_questions

Comment: I solved it. I used SHA1 of debug key store instead of my production key. That's the reason it was throwing this message only when i made apk to publish it. Anyways thanks for the comment.